# Microsoft VBA UserForm ToggleButton1 Not Changing its value after clicking

Tags: vba

```
Sub ssk()
UserForm.Show
UserForm.ToggleButton1.Value = False    '......this value is not changing
If UserForm.ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
MsgBox " true_ "
Else
MsgBox " false_ "
End If
end sub
```

Required Help in this...!

Comment: Your problem is not that the `ToggleButton1` doesn't change it's value - your problem is that the code is executed only when the Userform is closed: You open the form "Modal", and therefore the code execution of the Sub `ssk` is paused until the form is closed. Usually, it's better to put code that modifies the form into the form module, eg into trigger `Form_Activate`. Alternative is to open the form Non-modal (`UserForm.Show False`)

Answer (score 0):

The second line of the function sets the `ToggleButton1.Value` to false before it's value is tested. Removing the following line of code show fix this issue.

> ```
>  UserForm.ToggleButton1.Value = False    '......this value is not changing
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The toggle buttons default value is False, so no need to change it - unless you've set it to True in the properties window.

Add this code to a normal module.  It opens the form twice - just showing that you shouldn't use the default instance of the form, but create a new instance.  If the form is set to *ShowModal = True* then the second form will open when you close the first form, otherwise they will both open at the same time.

```
Sub Test()
    
    'The default value for a ToggleButton is False, so no need to change it.
    'You can change this in the ToggleButton properties.
    'StartUpPosition is default to 1 - CenterOwner.
    Dim frm As UserForm1
    Set frm = New UserForm1
    With frm
        .ToggleButton1.Caption = "First Form"
        .Show
    End With
    
    'If the form is set to ShowModal = False then two forms will open.
    'If ShowModal = True this code will execute when the first instance of the form closes.
    Dim Newfrm As UserForm1
    Set Newfrm = New UserForm1
    With Newfrm
        .StartUpPosition = 0 'Use manual positioning, so can place next to first form.
        .Left = frm.Left + frm.Width + 10
        
        .Top = frm.Top
        .ToggleButton1.Caption = "Second Form"
        .Show
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Inside the form have some code to deal with clicking the toggle button:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    MsgBox Me.ToggleButton1.Value, vbOKOnly, Me.ToggleButton1.Caption
End Sub
```

[image]